# Download DacPac with Power Shell Script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I've currently got a pipeline that builds and deploys DacPacs to our on-premise databases. However, we have some self-hosted clients who right now get a migration script on each release. We'd like to transition them to also being able to use DacPacs for deployments. I was wondering if it's possible to have a Powershell script that pulls the DacPac file from the artifacts directory on Azure  DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

> it's possible to have a Powershell script that pulls the DacPac file from the artifacts directory on Azure DevOps?

In Azure Pipeline, you need to publish the file to Build artifacts via [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops).

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop1'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dacpac file path'
    ArtifactName: drop
```

Then you could use the following Powershell script to download the target file:

```
 $token = "PAT"

$url1= "https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/builds/{BuildId}/artifacts?artifactName={ArtifactsName}&api-version=5.1"

$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

$containerid = $response1.resource.data
echo $containerid

$result= ("$containerid" -split "/")[1]

echo $result
    
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/resources/Containers/$($result)/{ArtifactsName}?itemPath={path to the item including the root}" #e.g.item file path drop%2FForumContext1.dacpac use %2F replace /
    
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
    
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/octet-stream -OutFile "C:\Response.dacpac"
```

On the other hand, Azure Devops also supports directly deploying the Dacpac file to on-premise database.

In Release Pipeline, you could use the SQL Server database deploy task in [Deployment Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) Job.

[image]